# Debugging a custom django management command

Tags: django

I can't find how to debug custom management commands.

When errors happen, they just say something like :

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How to get more debugging info ?

Like the number of the line where it crashes for instance, that would be helpful.

Comment: `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` or just remove wrong code from try/except block temporary.

Comment: Can't tell much without the code. You can use try/expect or an if on yourlist[0] to avoid the error

Comment: Use pdb. `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` as the first line in management command and step through the code.

Answer (score 19):

There is a traceback option that does the trick :

```
python manage.py command_name --traceback
```

The command then outputs usual python errors

Comment: You should accept this as the correct answer. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use `-i` option and pdb:

`python -i manage.py command_name`

failed or not , you will have a python repl, so you can use `pdb` to jump into the  stacks raising exception:

```
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/gary/PycharmProjects/borges-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute 
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gary/PycharmProjects/borges-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__          
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/gary/PycharmProjects/borges-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute 
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                    
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(10)                                                       

>>> import pdb                                                                                                                 
>>> pdb.pm()                                                                                                                   
> /home/gary/PycharmProjects/borges-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py(84)_execute()                 
-> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                                                                   
(Pdb) param  
blablabalablabalablbalbalabla
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [`CommandError`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.CommandError)
2. Use the [`python debugger`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).
3. Use [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).
4. Use an [error logging service](https://getsentry.com/welcome/).

Comment: first link is broken